# Minecraft Server: PHP echo $server->online_players

Tags: php, html

I have a problem with my website (http://www.zurfaria.ga/1/), where I'm trying to check how many players are online. I have downloaded this GitHub repository (https://github.com/mattvh/MCServerStatus) so I can query my server, but I can't seem to echo it in my HTML Here is my HTML and the PHP

```
    <?php

 require_once('/onlinecheck/Server.php')
 require_once('/onlinecheck/Stats.php')
 require_once('/onlinecheck/StatsException.php')

class MCServerStatus {

    public $server;
    public $online, $motd, $online_players, $max_players;
    public $error = "OK";

    function __construct($url, $port = '25565') {

        $this->server = array(
            "zurfaria.fmc.pw" => $url,
            "25565" => $port
        );

        if ( $sock = @stream_socket_client('tcp://'.$url.':'.$port, $errno, $errstr, 1) ) {

            $this->online = true;

            fwrite($sock, "\xfe");
            $h = fread($sock, 2048);
            $h = str_replace("\x00", '', $h);
            $h = substr($h, 2);
            $data = explode("\xa7", $h);
            unset($h);
            fclose($sock);

            if (sizeof($data) == 3) {
                $this->motd = $data[0];
                $this->online_players = (int) $data[1];
                $this->max_players = (int) $data[2];
            }
            else {
                $this->error = "Cannot retrieve server info.";
            }

        }
        else {
            $this->online = false;
            $this->error = "Cannot connect to server.";
        }

    }

}

?>

        <h1>Players Online:</h1>
        <?php 
        echo $server->online_players; //Outputs the number of players online 
        ?>
```

The HTML in between this code is fine, it works. What can I do to fix this? (I've looked up how to use the echo but didn't really understand it...)

Comment: Wait, you don't know how to use `echo`? In order to access `online_players` you need to create an instance of `MCServerStatus` (before `echo ...`: `$server = new MCServerStatus(...);`).

Comment: What is the value of `$server`?

Comment: Umm....I'm not at all knowledgeable with PHP, so heres a link to ALL of the code. http://www.zurfaria.ga/1/code.txt

Comment: Besides from the original problem, your file is `.html`. It should be `.php`.

Comment: Also, you should read the complete [tutorial](http://www.webmaster-source.com/2012/07/05/checking-the-status-of-a-minecraft-server-with-php/) linked on that github page...

Comment: Thanks! That really helped! I hadn't seen that, because I was linked to the GitHub page, didn't bother looking at the top text...